# How to plot figures but keeping them minimized in the taskbar?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Is there a way to actually create figures in matlab and keep them minimized in the taskbar?

I know I can use

```
h=figure;
set(h, 'Visible', 'off');
```

but in this way in the taskbar there is no figure icon.

I simply like to plot something but keep it minimized in the taskbar: how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matlab doesn't have built-in functions to do this, so the second best thing to do would be to use Java.

This is plucked straight from [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/minimize-maximize-figure-window):

```
plot(1:10);
jFrame = get(handle(gcf),'JavaFrame');
pause(0.1)  %//This is important
jFrame.setMinimized(true);
```

The `pause` is necessary because you'd otherwise get a `NullPointerException` because of the fact that the window hasn't been fully drawn yet.

Comment: You wrote "second best thing". Is there actually a better way?

Comment: @Marco What I meant by that was Mathworks should get working on a native implementation instead of having us rely on Java. (To answer you question directly, no, there is no better way; the other methods rely on OS-specific APIs)